# Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema

Tags: mysql

I have upgraded my server machine to use MySQL Connector 6.3.4 and in our website we also added Membership role provider.

When I run the website I am getting this error.

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema.

My sql server is version 5.0.90 community-net.

Is there any  setting which have to be changes on server side while upgrading connector

This is tag in my web.config file.

Since when I run the website on local machine it will run successfully, but on server I am not able to run it and getting above error.
There is no mistake in connection string

What are server side setting which we to do while upgrading the connector....

thanks

Answer (score 6):

I myself running into the same problem. I m using Mysql connector 6.3.0.0
So far I came across following suggestions when seaching on net:

```
1) Add "MySql.Data.dll" & "MySql.Web.dll" into your application  "bin" folder.
2) Add reference to above to dlls in your application .
3) Add autogenerateschema="true" in your web.config file for required sections.
4) Check your Mysql connector version - make sure that the one that is in your bin folder is mentioned in your web.config file. 
5) Check your connection string - make sure it is correct and connected successfully.
6) Check mysql membership related table structure.
7) Check schema version in "my_aspnet_schemaversion" table (e.g since you have upgraded to newer version I insist you should check this).
8) If the problem is on remote machine (e.g Production Server) you may wan to check this : http://www.reggieburnett.com/referencing-connectornet-on-a-remote-machine
```

I m sure you may gone through this list but I would like you to check schema version in "my_aspnet_schemaversion" table (e.g compare "version" field value of your local and remote table) since your upgrading to newer version.

BTW: I have checked this list for my problem but it did not help. I hope it may be of some help to you.

**Edit**:
Hi,
We are able to fix this error by following:

```
1) Deleted the tables for memberships in the db and had the mysql membership provider regenerate them
2) than set the Aministration.config file to trust the Mysql Membership Provider (e.g related to IIS admin)
```

Regards,

Gaurav

Comment: Hey Gaurav! How did you do the second step of your "Edit" section. I have found the Administration.config file but don't know how to make it trust the Mysql Membership Provider

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure that the Datasource is set to the real ip address and not localhost and check the passwords and usernames too. I am working with these clients and their ip address keeps changing and every time they do that, I get the same error

Comment: Your right, somehow localhost did not work anymore, why not?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem after checking all the things in Gaurav's post. It ended up being that the user account I was using in my connection string did not have necessary permissions to alter the db schema (I had autogenerateschema set to true).  Once I changed my connection string to a user with more privileges (I used the 'root' user) then it updated the schema, and I changed the connection string back to the original user.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but maybe this will help someone. I was having this issue and realized that I was editing the wrong machine.config

At first I was editing on under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64....
Once I found the one for my .NET version under C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework.... and edited the correct spots, it worked fine following the instructions on MySQL's site.