# Membership tables are incorrect using local service

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I have:

- MVC 3
- MySQL using .NET Connector 6.4.4

Everything is ok if i connect from local PC with VS2010 to remote DB on Linux. I made a backup to have DB locally and install the same version of MySQL (5.5, x64)

On remote i have normal .net autogenerated table names for membership, like `my_aspnet_membership`, but when i start applicantion locally it create other table names, like `mysql_membership`. Also i got the exception: `Unable to initialize provider.  Missing or incorrect schema.`

With same settings, but with connection to Remote DB everything works fine.

```
<add name="MySqlSessionStateProvider" type="MySql.Web.SessionState.MySqlSessionStateStore, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" applicationName="/" autogenerateschema="true" connectionStringName="MySqlMembershipConnection" />
```

Does anybody know where is the problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the .NET Connector 6.4.4 but does the " autogenerateschema="true" "generate your SQL schema on the fly?

Comment: Can you connect to the database and read the tables using the same connection string from a unit test or simple console app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is in configuration. See following posts:

1. [Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=53076)
2. http://forums.asp.net/t/1557879.aspx/1
3. [Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema. for MySql.Web connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393131/unable-to-initialize-provider-missing-or-incorrect-schema-for-mysql-web-connec)
4. [Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699688/unable-to-initialize-provider-missing-or-incorrect-schema)
5. [Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858182/unable-to-initialize-provider-missing-or-incorrect-schema-in-mysql)
6. [MVC2 MySQL Hosting Issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983622/mvc2-mysql-hosting-issue)